"key not present in the dictionary" Exception despite actually existing
I have a Dictionary<FileInfo, FileStream>
Doing some tests with it. I have a single item in the dictionary. The FileInfo is X:\Thumper\levels\Basics3\sequin.master. But when I try to obtain that entry by passing in LoadedFile, which is also a FileInfo intialized to X:\Thumper\levels\Basics3\sequin.master, I get this exception that the key was not present.
You can clearly see lockedfiles[0] is that file path. So I'm not sure why LoadedFile doesn't match the key.


Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

Two FileInfo objects are not the same just because they contain the same file name.  If you want the key to be the name, then you should use a string.

To add to the comment above by @TimRoberts - something similar will apply to many reference types, but to illustrate why FileInfo is particularly unsuitable as a Dictionary key, see this Q&A. A FileInfo is a snapshot, which means (for example) that its .Exists property will continue to return true after the file has been deleted - a nasty "gotcha" for the unwary.

I guess use the dictionary key as string Dictionary<string, FileStream>. The key will be FullName of file (full path).
And then use dictionary like this:
Dictionary<string, FileStream> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, FileStream>();
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(fullName, out FileStream fileStram))
{
// use fileStream here
}

